# Why does "overflow-y:hidden" affect the visibility of items overflowing on the x axis?

Tags: html, css

Consider this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/P8JbW/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="http://ycombinator.com/images/y18.gif" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#test {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    overflow-x:visible;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left:-11px;
}
```

I'm expecting to see this:

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]

It seems that the overflow-x property is being overridden here. Is that what's actually happening? Assuming that I have to keep the overflow-y set to hidden, is there a way around this behavior?

Comment: This is very interesting. I can confirm this is happening in Chrome 9, FF 3.6, & Safari 5. If someone could check if this is occurring in the various IE versions that'd be useful to know.

Comment: IE 7 is the same. IE6 shows the whole image.

Comment: @Alohci: fortunately, I no longer have to code to IE6 ;-)

Comment: That's good. Now if we can just point out to clients that IE7 has an even lower market share than IE6 and we shouldn't be coding for that either, we'll be making real progress ...

Comment: This is happening on the newest Chrome. Was CSS so poorly developed? lol

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`overflow` is intended to be used with elements that are not absolutely positioned. If you want to handle the clipping of an absolutely positioned element, use [the `clip` css property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping). So to clip on the bottom and top of your containing div, but not the left or right, do this:

```
#test {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,-11px);
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/UJNcf/6/

Comment: Thanks for this! A workaround is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow I'd never heard of `clip`, awesome.

Comment: Maybe this has help the OP, But it does not answer his question. Andrew Marshall's answer #answer-5072540 does.

Comment: FYI: `clip` is deprecated. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

Answer (score 24):

From the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow):

> The computed values of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with `visible` are not possible: if one is specified as `visible` and the other is `scroll` or `auto`, then `visible` is set to `auto`. The computed value of `overflow` is equal to the computed value of `overflow-x` if `overflow-y` is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`.

From this it would seem that some combinations of `overflow-x` & `overflow-y` are not valid, and sometimes one will override the other, which would explain what you're seeing here. Though I'm unsure as the wording as a bit unclear and the way browsers actually implement it could vary from the spec (especially when it's hard to decipher).

Comment: Very interesting...thanks for the info. Incidentally, I also was able to find this useful page that shows how all of the combinations affect one another: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html