# Why does overflow-x:hidden clip my descenders?

Tags: css, overflow

I would like to have a title element with `overflow-x:hidden` and `overflow-y:visible`. However, for some reason the `overflow-y` property does not seem to be obeyed. You can observe this here (tested on Chrome and Firefox):
http://jsfiddle.net/YgsAw/3/

In that demo, I expect to see "jjjjj", but instead the j's are cut off and look more like 1's.

If I set `overflow-x:visible` on the `h1` tag then suddenly the full height of the text is visible, but setting `overflow-x:hidden` makes it clipped. I would expect this behavior from `overflow-y`, but that seems to have no effect. Why is this, and what can I do about it?

Comment: My workaround was to add a bit of extra padding to the bottom of the container.

Comment: @Qaz that kind of fix does work---and in reality these are the kinds of things we all do to get the job done---but it deeply irritates my sensibilities. How much padding, exactly, do I need to be *certain* everything will be visible on every platform? Will that padding affect my layout and make it uglier? There are tradeoffs to consider. I eventually opted for the hack suggested at the bottom of the accepted answer, which adds additional HTML nodes but retains precise control over the element height and guarantees vertical overflow will always be visible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found some answers in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072467/why-does-overflow-yhidden-affect-the-visibility-of-items-overflowing-on-the-x). According to [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow):

> The computed values of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with `visible` are not possible: if one is specified as `visible` and the other is `scroll` or `auto`, then `visible` is set to `auto`. The computed value of `overflow` is equal to the computed value of `overflow-x` if `overflow-y` is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`.

Furthermore, on [this page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) the author mentions that many browsers impose additional restrictions:

> In Gecko, Safari, Opera, ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ also when combined with ‘hidden’ (in other words: ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ when combined with anything else different from ‘visible’).

That same page also provides demos for all possible combinations where this effect can be observed.

I am not aware of a viable workaround for my situation.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure I can do what I want by nesting my title tag in another tag: `<div><h1>title</h1></div>`. The inner `h1` has `line-height:normal` to make everything vertically visible, as well as `overflow:hidden` to make it truncate. The outer element can have a strictly limited height and `overflow:visible`. It's not ideal, but it seems like the best option.

Comment: The spec was all I could find but it isn't relevant to your question - on the other hand I wasn't aware of any UA-specific behavior, and that seems to hit the nail right on the head. Indeed, there doesn't seem to be any viable workaround for your situation. It's interesting to note, though, that you can give focus to your `h1` and scroll it to see the descenders :) (`overflow` other than `visible` doesn't stop something from scrolling; it only causes visual clipping)

Answer (score 3):

It seems changing the H1 element into an inline element will get you the desired results:

```
h1 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;        
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    display:inline;
}
```

Just make sure the following element is a block element so it doesn't start in the same line. That or use the correct line-height and then use negative margins. After all, I can only guess what you're trying to do... Good luck!

Comment: I think this is because inline elements do not obey the overflow property at all. It makes no sense for them.

Unfortunately this won't work for me. The goal is to use `white-space:nowrap` and `text-overflow:ellipsis` to make the title cut itself short if it is too long. I don't think I can get this to work properly for an inline element.

Comment: @Calvin: Yes, that is correct. I just reviewed the spec, which says [it only applies to block containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) (this includes inline blocks).